# Send Telegram bot messages to a Wordpress REST endpoint?

Tags: wordpress, telegram, telegram-bot, wordpress-rest-api

I'm trying to build a pseudo online chat with a telegram bot on a Wordpress website. I'm noob with Wordpress' REST API and Telegram API, but I thought this was easy.

For displaying the messages sent from an admin to the users, I thought it could use a Wordpress REST endpoint. So I set the webhook into Telegram:

```
curl -F "url=https://www.example.com/wp-json/mybot/bot" -F "certificate=@/path/to/my/certificate.crt" https://api.telegram.org/bot<my-bot-token>/setWebhook
```

And created the custom endpoint within wordpress:

```
add_action('rest_api_init', array( $this, 'set_telegram_message_endpoint' ));

function set_telegram_message_endpoint()
{
    register_rest_route('mybot', 'bot', array(
        'methods' => 'POST',
        'callback' => 'get_telegram_message' ),
    ));
}
```

So I suppose I can catch messages sent to my bot in this endpoint:

```
function get_telegram_message( WP_REST_REQUEST $request )
{
    print_r( $request->get_body() );
}
```

But instead I'm getting a 'code:rest_no_route' ... 'status:404' json message.

Is this even doable, and if it is, what I'm doing wrong?

---

### Edit 1

As @Nikita Durarev's asked, here follows the full class I wrote for this:

```
class Chat
{
    private static $token, $telegram;

    public function __construct()
    {
        self::$token = <TELEGRAM-BOT-TOKEN>;
        self::$telegram = "https://api.telegram.org:443/bot" . self::$token;

        add_action('rest_api_init', array( $this, 'set_telegram_message_endpoint' ));
        add_action('admin_post_chat_form', array( $this, 'chat_telegram' ));
        add_action('admin_post_nopriv_chat_form', array( $this, 'chat_telegram' ));
    }

    public function set_telegram_message_endpoint()
    {
        register_rest_route('mybot', 'bot', array(
            'methods' => 'GET',
            'callback' => array( $this, 'get_telegram_message' ),
        ));
    }

    public function get_telegram_message( WP_REST_REQUEST $request )
    {
        print_r( $request->get_body() );
    }

    public function chat_telegram( $input = null )
    {
        $mensaje = $input === '' ? $_POST['texto'] : $input;
        echo $mensaje;

        $query = http_build_query([
            'chat_id' => <TELEGRAM-CHAT-ID>,
            'text' => $mensaje,
            'parse_mode' => "Markdown",
        ]);

        $response = file_get_contents( self::$telegram . '/sendMessage?' . $query );
        return $response;
    }
}
```

Comment: I'll try to help you, but please answer me what does this `$get_telegram_message` variable mean? If you wanna call back function `get_telegram_message`, you need to write `'get_telegram_message'`

Comment: Read this manual - https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/extending-the-rest-api/adding-custom-endpoints/

Comment: Sorry, that was a typo. I meant 'get_telegram_message' - I was just shorting this as I wrote this for OOP. Thank for the link to the manual, but I still don't know what could be wrong

Comment: Okay, can you write please full code, for example full class?

Comment: @NikitaDudarev - Sure, here you go. Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

Finally managed to solve it (I guess). Seems I misunderstood the `methods` variable into the `register_rest_route` function.

So I changed this:

```
'methods' => 'GET',
```

For this:

```
'methods' => WP_REST_SERVER::CREATABLE,
```

That way I could send POST requests to the endpoint via cURL or postman, [as stated in the Telegram wiki](https://core.telegram.org/bots/webhooks#testing-your-bot-with-updates) and get the JSON object it was sent to the endpoint.

Many thanks to @NikitaDudarev for his/her willing to help.